# Python dataframe element to define a range() statement in a loop

Tags: python, pandas

This is a python type conversion question. I couldn't find an existing answer so if there is answer please point me to it.

What I want to do is, take a cell value

```
cell_value = df.iloc[[row_index_value]]['column_A']
```

And use it as range in a nested loop, like so

```
for x in range(cell_value):
```

This fails because cell_value is a Series object:

```
for row_index_value in range(3):
    
    cell_value = df.iloc[[row_index_value]]['column_A']
    print(cell_value)
```

```
0    1
Name: column_A, dtype: int64
1    3
Name: column_A, dtype: int64
2    3
Name: column_A, dtype: int64
```

Conversion to .astype(int) still fails as shown below

```
# demo snippet
for row_index_value in range(3):
    
    cell_value = df.iloc[[row_index_value]]['column_A']
    print("cell val =",cell_value)
    
    # TypeError: 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
    for x in range(cell_value.astype(int)): 
        print("x # =", x)
```

I managed a working solution using conversion to a unitary-element list and then accessing the list element, like so

```
for row_index_value in range(3):
    
    cell_value = df.iloc[[row_index_value]]['column_A']
    cell_value = cell_value.to_list()[0]
    print(cell_value)
    
    # Now the nested loop runs
    for x in range(cell_value): 
        print("x # =", x)
```

Although this works, I think there ought to be a better conversion statement. Open to any suggestions.

Comment: `df.at[row_index_value, 'column_A']` is what you're looking for

Comment: I think you're using the row label directly, rather than raw index count? If so, `df.loc[index_val, column_name]`.